# PL/SQL creating a trigger problems

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have to create a trigger on an Employee table.  If an INSERT or UPDATE statement is issued for the Employee table the trigger launches and makes sure that the value of 'salary' field meets the criteria in the job_min_sal table. After trying over and over I got a mutating table error and now am very frustrated and don't know what to do.

```
 JOB_MIN_SALARY TABLE:
  JOB VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY
  MIN_SAL NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL
```

The JOB_MIN_SAL table is populated with a variety of job titles and salaries.  I am confused working with my trigger and wondering if I could get some assistance where to go from here

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_job_salary
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF SALARY on employee
     FOR EACH ROW
     DECLARE 
      v_salary    NUMBER;


    BEGIN
      SELECT minimum_salary
      INTO v_salary
      FROM job_min_salary
      WHERE UPPER(job) = UPPER(:NEW.job);
```

I know I am really far off I am just looking for help as for what this requires and what steps I need to take to get this. Thanks!

```
 The EMPLOYEE table:

 (
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(4)
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
    JOB VARCHAR2(50)
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(4)
    HIRE_DATE DATE
    SALARY NUMBER(9)
    COMMISION NUMBER(9)
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
 );
```

Comment: What is the rest of your trigger? The part you've shown shouldn't give a mutating table error.

Comment: The code you posted would not throw a mutating trigger error.  It would, however, generate a syntax error since the name of the table `JOB_MIN_SAL` doesn't match the name of the table you are selecting `JOB_MINIMUM_SALARY` and the column name is mismatched as well (`MIN_SAL` vs. `MINIMUM_SALARY`).  The code you posted is also missing an `END`.  If you are actually getting a mutating trigger error, your example is missing whatever logic is creating that error.

Comment: @AlexPoole I was just stating I was getting that error before. I started fresh and Im not sure where to go from this point.  And I updated the names of the tables since I just typed them in here real quick and did not copy and paste as I should have.

Comment: @DaBulls33 Did you figure out something from that link https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=or]&gbv=2&oq=or]&gs_l=hp.3...2017.3074.0.3085.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.vlEMBr_83BI#hl=en&gs_rn=16&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&pq=oracle%20mutating%20table&cp=22&gs_id=12u&xhr=t&q=oracle+mutating+table+trigger&es_nrs=true&pf=p&gbv=2&sclient=psy-ab&oq=oracle+mutating+table+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bGE&fp=766d36efbf18eb61&biw=1319&bih=877 ? If so, what you think about possible cause of such error?

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem at this point? You don't specify what the criteria are, and what action should be taken.  Normally, you would have some coniditional test that if failed, would raise an exception.

Comment: This sounds familiar ... Duplicate question I think...

Answer (score 0):

i am supposing you are doing something like
comparing new salary with min salary criterion and update only if :new.SALARY >= v_salary

what are you doing if this is not met, are u trapping an exception or just ignoring the error or returning an error code to debug.

post more info

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE job_min_salary
(
    job     VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    min_sal NUMBER(7,2)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO job_min_salary VALUES('CEO','100');
-- 1 rows inserted.

CREATE TABLE employee
(
    employee_id     NUMBER(4),
    employee_name   VARCHAR2(20),
    job             VARCHAR2(50),
    manager_id      NUMBER(4),
    hire_date       DATE,
    salary          NUMBER(9),
    commision       NUMBER(9),
    department_id   NUMBER(4)
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1, 'Name', 'CEO', 1, TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 80, 80, 1);
-- 1 rows inserted.

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_job_salary
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF salary ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    v_salary  NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT  1
    INTO    v_salary
    FROM    job_min_salary
    WHERE   UPPER(job)  = UPPER(:NEW.job)
    AND     :NEW.salary >= min_sal;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'Salary value is too low for given job');
END;
-- TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_JOB_SALARY compiled

SELECT * FROM employee;
-- 1    Name    CEO 1   2000-01-01 00:00:00 80  80  1

UPDATE employee
SET    salary = 10
WHERE  job    = 'CEO';
-- ORA-20999: Salary value is too low for given job

UPDATE employee
SET    salary = 100
WHERE  job    = 'CEO';
-- 1 rows updated.

SELECT * FROM employee;
-- 1    Name    CEO 1   2000-01-01 00:00:00 100 80  1
```